# Convert lighttpd rewrite rule to nginx

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting, lighttpd

I have the following simple `lighttpd` rewrite rule:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^(app\.mydomain\.com)$" {
    url.rewrite-once = (
            "^[^.]*$" => "controller.php/$1"
    )
}
```

I am trying to port this rule to `nginx` and have the following:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name app.mydomain.com;

  if ($host = 'app.mydomain.com') {
    rewrite ^[^.]*$ controller.php/$1 last;
  }

  root /srv/www/domains/app.mydomain.com;

  index index.php;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/domains/app.mydomain.com/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/domains/app.mydomain.com/error.log;

  include /etc/nginx/excludes.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/php.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/expires.conf;
}
```

The problem is that the rewrite rule for nginx is not working correctly? Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need a slash in front of `controller.php` and you probably don't need the if block around rewrite because it's the servername for the vhost anyways.

```
rewrite ^[^.]*$ /controller.php/$1 last;
```